# Resources for finding all drugs of a certain class

Tags: pharmacology

I may be embarking on a project involving a fairly extensive healthcare records data set, looking for the use of a particular type of drug (for example, "Proton Pump Inhibitors"). But these drugs are usually listed by their trade or generic names - is there a well maintained resource for looking up what drugs are members of a certain class (if class is indeed the right word)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [WHO](http://www.who.int/en/) has their own methodology, the Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical (ATC, thank you commenter) [classification system](http://www.whocc.no/atc/structure_and_principles/), for organizing such data (its impetus is comparing results between studies).

Also, if you have $900 sitting around, you can get a [subscription](http://store.usp.org/OA_HTML/usp2_ibeCCtpSctDspRte.jsp?section=10071&minisite=10020) for the United States Pharmacopeia.  I'm not sure if that can be spread across multiple subscriptions for an organization like the Red Book David mentions.

Comment: +1 for the links & mention. Does WHO publish any public data we can use? That could be interesting...

Comment: @DavidP.Hochman I think all of the WHO's data are public, but I don't know where it is published.

Answer (score 9):

Comprehensive, up-to-date drug information including trade names and categories are available from [Micromedex®](http://www.micromedex.com) (a division of Thomson Reuters) in the [RED BOOK](http://www.micromedex.com/products/redbook/).

It's free to use anywhere (even on a mobile device) by anyone in your organization ... *after* you pay the subscription fee.  The fee for research is much less than the fee for commercial use.